# python3 group items in list seperated by at least three empty items

Tags: python, python-3.x

How might I group items in this example list:

```
input = ['a','b',' c', '', '', '', 'd','e','f','','k','j']

desired output = ['ab c','defkj']
```

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: why did `'d','e','f','','k','j'` turn into `'defkj'` be clear of what you want and post your efforts.

Comment: Most probably because they aren't separated by >=3 empty string entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
lst = ['a','b',' c', '', '', '', 'd','e','f','','k','j']

res_lst = []
res_str = ''
for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    res_str += item # Add current item to res_str

    # If next 3 items result is an empty string
    # and res_str has value
    if not ''.join(lst[i+1:i+3]) and res_str:
        res_lst.append(res_str)
        res_str = ''

print(res_lst)
```

**Note:** Don't use `input` as a variable name (unless you're just using that to demonstrate what an example input is) as it will override the built-in `input` method.